# How do I add a CSS3 transition to an image overlay?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to give a semi-transparent image overlay (that appears on :hover) a CSS3 transition (ease). But it's not working. I'm not sure if it's because I'm missing something, or if transitions just don't work with the display property. Any ideas for a CSS workaround (I don't know JavaScript)? Thanks in advance.

Relevant HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <figure>
        <img src="images/dude.jpg" alt=""/>
    </figure>
    <div class="thumbnail-overlay">
        <h2>Project Name</h2>
        <h3> Skills Skills Skills</h3>
        <p>This is a project description.</p>
    </div>
</div>

.thumbnail {
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   width:40%;
   margin:1.5% 1.5% 0 0;
}

.thumbnail-overlay {
   background-color: @dark-gray;
   display:none;
   opacity:.9;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%; height:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   -webkit-transition:all .3s ease;
   -moz-transition:all .3s ease;
   transition:all.3s ease;
}


.thumbnail:hover .thumbnail-overlay {
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: The display property can NOT be animated (only two states). But opacity and even visibility can.

Answer (score 0):

as i see it is because display property. css transition doesn't work good with it and that's why you have this probleme.

here is the css code that i tested and work's ok:

```
.thumbnail .thumbnail-overlay {
background-color: @dark-gray;
display:block;
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%; height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.thumbnail:hover .thumbnail-overlay {
opacity: .9;
}
```

hope it helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me.I seperated the CSS to another file and linked it to the HTML file.It works nice for me

HTML

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <figure>
            <img src="/home/qbadmin/Downloads/Pic.jpg" alt=""/>
        </figure>
    <div class="thumbnail-overlay">
        <h2>Project Name</h2>
        <h3> Skills Skills Skills</h3>
        <p>This is a project description.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .thumbnail {
      position:absolute;
      float:left;
      width:40%;
      left :100 px;
      top :100px;
      margin:1.5% 1.5% 0 0;
      }

     .thumbnail-overlay {
     background-color: @dark-gray;
     display:none;
     opacity:.9;
     position:absolute;
     top:100px;
     left:100px;
     width:100%; height:100%;
     overflow:hidden;
     -webkit-transition:all .3s ease;
     -moz-transition:all .3s ease;
      transition:all.3s ease;
      }

     .thumbnail:hover .thumbnail-overlay {
      display:block;
      opacity: .9;
       }
```